# Change child element background CSS

Tags: html, css

I am a novice at CSS, here's HTML structure:

```
<nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-sm">
    <a class="navbar-brand ml-4" href="#">
        <img src="images/logo-light.svg" alt="" width="30" height="90" class="d-inline-block align-top" id="navlogo">
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed border-0" id="navbar-toggler" type="button">
        <span> </span>
        <span> </span>
        <span> </span>
    </button>
</nav>
```

What I need to do is if I add a class "black" to `navbar` I need the css background color on `navbar-toggler` to turn white. How do I do that with CSS?

I thought it should be like:

```
. navbar .black .navbar-toggler span{
    background: #000 !important;
}
```

but it's not working

Comment: Maybe `.black > .navbar-toggler{background-color: white;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close.

By going `.navbar .black`, you are targeting `.black` that is inside `.navbar`. But by doing `.navbar.black` you are targeting the element that has both `.navbar` and `.black`.

```
.navbar.black .navbar-toggler span{
    background: #FFF!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript addEventListener

```js
const nav = document.querySeletor('#navbar)
('#navbar_toggler').addEventListener('toggle',function(){
    nav.classList.toggle('bg')
  
})
```

```css
.bg{
background-color:black;
}
```

Comment: No need for JS, I want to use CSS

Comment: if you only want to turn text color white only once, then use class text-light